# Trying to set a record's value based on a field via string. Is this dynamic approach possible in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, metadata, string, dynamic, fieldsets

Apologies if this was already answered, but I didn't see a clear cut solution for this issue in Salesforce. I want to be able to dynamically set values for a record based on a predefined list of strings. However having some trouble on where to start...

```
Lead soqledLead = [select id, Name, Age__c,LastName,Company FROM Lead where Id = '00Q0y00001XeivU'];
Lead singleLead = new Lead();
List<String> listOfFieldsViaAPIname = new list<String> { 'Name','Age__c', 'LastName', 'Company'  };

for(String s : listOfFieldsViaAPIname){
    system.debug('API Name ====>' +s);
    singleLead.s = soqledLead.s;
    //^this will obviously fail (Variable does not exist: s)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a matter using the right functions, namely `get` and `put`, from the [`sObject` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

```
for(String s : listOfFieldsViaAPIname){
    singleLead.put(s, soqledLead.get(s)); 
}
```

Could also stand to make your query use your fields, could also make those fields into a fieldset, but thats out of scope of this question.

Comment: PERFECT!!! I've never utilized get/put like that. And actually yes I have all of those fields in a fieldSet, just wanted to simplify the question for this post.

Comment: Any `sObject` (Most Salesforce standard objects, plus custom objects) will have these methods exposed- very useful to write code which doesn't have to care about the values, fields or types of the data its working with. I'll always add little blurbs like that, mostly for future users, or in case OP (you) is newish to the platform. Very nice to write code which performs some basic operation off of a list of fields which you can modify on production without needing to make code changes.